# Open Source GUI in ROS for AMRs

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, mobile-robot, gui

are there any available web based GUI/HMI for operating AMRs with ROS. Im looking for any packages that have basic functionalitie for AMRs. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sort of, not really. There are the robot web tools (https://robotwebtools.github.io/) but they are not very well maintained. I'm the founder and author of https://transitiverobotics.com/, an open-source framework for full-stack robotics, incl. web GUIs. Using this platform you can build web GUIs for robots more easily. But we also have some ready-to-go components such as remote-teleop you can integrate into any web-app. These communicate with your robot via an agent you install. These capabilities are not open-source though. Reach out on our Slack (link on homepage) if you want to chat.